# Is a constant function well-defined?

Tags: functions, definition

I am trying to understand what a function being well-defined means.

I see some other answers which say that it is:

$f: A \rightarrow B$ is well-defined if for each $a \in A$, there is a unique $b \in B$ with $f(a) = b$.

Does this mean that a constant function, e.g. $f(x) = 3$ is not well defined? There is not a unique b.

Thank you

Comment: "For each $ a\in A$, there is a unique $b\in B$  with $ f(a)=b$". Can you see the dependence of $b$ on $a$?

Comment: It means that that if $f(a)=b_{1}$ and $f(a)=b_{2}$ then it must mean that $b_{1}=b_{2}$ . In otherwords if $a_{1}=a_{2}$ then $f(a_{1})=f(a_{2})$ must hold. That is the same element in the domain cannot map to two different element in the range. However different elements in the domain can map to same elements in the range.

Comment: The term 'well defined' usually arises in a context where the function is defined indirectly, or requires some work to show that the has a unique value and is defined everywhere on the specified domain. There is no such issue with constant functions. For example, a linear operator has an determinant, regardless of the choice of basis, but you need to do some work to show that the choice of basis does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

To talk about "well-defined functions" is a common abuse of terminology, but it is misleading. I think it is better to think about whether a given binary relation $R(x, y)$ defines a function: that's what happens in practice: we write down a relation like:
$$
y^2 = x
$$
and ask whether that relation defines $y$ as a function of $x$, i.e., whether, for every $x$ there exists a unique $y$ such that $R(x, y)$, i.e., such that $y^2 = x$. And then the answer depends on what values we allow $x$ and $y$ to range over: (1) if we allow $x, y$ to range over $\Bbb{N}$, then the above does not give us a function, since for some $x$ (e.g., $2$) there is no $y$ in our allowed range with $y^2 = x$ (existence fails); (2) if we allow $x, y$ to range over $\Bbb{C}$, then the above does not give us a function because for all $x \neq 0$, there are two choices for a $y$ such that $y^2 = x$ (uniqueness fails). We do get a function if we let $x$ and $y$ both range over non-negative reals.

[Aside: we can be more liberal and say that in case (1) above, we have a *partial* function, while in case (2) above, we have a *multi-valued* function. But these are just terminological conveniences for (1) functions defined on subsets and (2) functions taking values in sets.]

In your example, the relation:
$$
y = 3
$$
is a bit odd considered as a relation between $x$ and $y$ (since $x$ isn't mentioned) but that isn't really a problem. For every $x$ in any set, there is a unique $y$ (namely $3$) such that $y = 3$ and so the above relation defines a function $X \to Y$ for any set $X$ and any set $Y$ such that $3 \in Y$.

Answer (score 1):

A constant function is well defined.

When we define a function $y = f(x)$ then for any given $x$, the function should return only a single $y$, which is a scalar.

If the function returns a vector, for instance:
$r(t) = f_1(t) \hat{i} + f_2(t) \hat{j}$
then it is called a vector-valued function. Note that even in this case, there is a single output for any t.

In case we have a mapping where for any given $x$, $f$ returns multiple $y$ (i.e. a set), then it is no more a function rather it is called set-valued mapping.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is this: you're proposing that well-definedness means (expressed symbolically)

$$(\forall b \in B)(\exists ! \, a \in A)(f(a) = b)$$

This should seem silly on the face of it, because it immediately excludes all non-injective functions (constant functions included). The proper definition is that

$$(\forall a \in A)(\exists ! \, b \in B)(f(a) = b)$$

---

Phrased differently, your thinking is stuck in the idea that this $b$ must be unique in a global sense, that only a single $a$ can satisfy $f(a) = b$.

That's not what that means.

It means, given a value $a$, there is one and only one value $b$ (possibly dependent on $a$) whereby $f(a) = b$. You cannot have $f(a)$ equal two or more distinct values (e.g. you cannot have $f(1) = 1$ and $f(1) = 100$), and you cannot have it equal nothing at all (e.g. $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=1/x$ is ill-defined because there is no value for $f(0)$).

Comment: Thank you very much!